# How do you make an http get request that returns a json array which will be used to fill an ngfor directive?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-http

I want to make an http get request that returns a json array of data that is to be used in an `ngFor` loop. I am not sure the best way to do this. `this.list` is the list to be looped through in the `ngFor` directive. For testing purposes, the json file is located on my local machine. I've looked through the Angular 2 documentation, as well as a udemy course for this, but can't figure it out. I suspect it is something simple.

The component with the `ngFor` directive.

```
constructor(private router:Router, private rec:RecommendationsService ){}
      ngOnInit(){
        this.rec.getRecommendations().subscribe(
          data=>{
            this.x = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(this.x);
            this.list = this.x;
          }
        );
      }
```

The get request is located in a service

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RecommendationsService{

  url="//Users/Daniel/Desktop/Reccomendations.json";

  constructor(private http:Http){};

  getRecommendations(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json);
  }
}
```

This is the ngfor that needs the data.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of list, let i = index" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recModal">
                <div class="row rowTopBuffer rowDiv" (click)="toModal(item.name, item.description, item.recLocLat, item.recLocLong, item.picturePath)">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 titleDiv" >
                        <img class="recommendationImages img-responsive img-rounded" src={{item.picturePath}}>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 descDiv">

                    <p class="itemTitle">{{item.name}}</p>
                    <p id="{{desc+i}}">{{item.description}}</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Right now EXCEPTION: [object Object] is thrown in the console when running this code.

Comment: Can you show us your template code, too?

Comment: Yes I put it up, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't stringify that object again, since you can't loop through a string :)

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.rec.getRecommendations().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.x = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(this.x);
            this.list = data;
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("done")
    );
}
```

Also in your service call the 'json()' method like this:

```
getRecommendations(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

And in your template you have a faulty `ngFor` usage. Use `;` instead of `,` to seperate the index.

```
*ngFor="let item of list; let i = index"
```

Comment: Thanks, I made those corrections but, it doesnt help. My get method does not seem to be getting the data at all.

Comment: Yeah... just EXCEPTION: [object Object]

Comment: Try and add error logging to the subscribe call - see my edit!

Comment: I did, now I get in the console Object { _body: error, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }

Comment: Please try and remove the `.json()` in the `map()` call. If it's still returning an error, I'm 99% sure it can't access the JSON file.

Comment: when I do that, a really cryptic alert message appears, and then it prints out done in the console...So yeah i think you're right.

Comment: Maybe try and put your JSON file besides your `index.html` and set the `url` to `Reccomendations.json`. Don't forget to add back the `res.json()`

Comment: Youre amazing, thank you! it seems wierd that it was not able to find the json file from that location.

Answer (score 1):

After working a lot more with angular, Ive learned a lot and would like to add an answer to this question. You can return the interface itself, or you can return a class that implements the interface like so. Angular will take care of the deserialisation itself.

*************HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i = index;">
  <div>employee.Name</div>
  <div>employee.Id</div>
</div>
```

*************Typescript class and interface

```
export interface Employee{
  Id:number;
  Name:string;
}

export class ResponseEmployee implements Employee{
  Id:number;
  Name:string;
}
```

*************** Http service

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeHttpService {


  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getEmployees(city:string){

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var url = “/api/endpoint/path”;

    return this.http
      .get(url, {headers:headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then((res)=> res.json() as ResponseEmployee[]);

  }

}
```

**************** Component that uses employeeHttpService

```
@Component({
  selector: 'display-recommendations',
  templateUrl: './display-recommendations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-recommendations.component.sass']
})
export class DisplayEmployees implements OnInit {

  employees:ResponseEmployee[]=[];

  constructor(private employeeHttp:EmployeeHttpService){}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.employeeHttp.getEmployees()
      .then((data: ResponseEmployee[])=> {
        this.employees = data;
      })
      .catch((e:Error)=> this.handleError(e));
  }



}
```